# Cannot retrieve image from Firebase Storage: Object does not exist at location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having a problem in my app. I uploaded images to Firebase Storage and now I cannot retrieve it, I'm having an error saying:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

my code for this is like following:

```
private void getImage() {
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://bucket");
        mStorageReference = mStorage.getReference().child("/animal_images/animals" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        mStorageReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(bytes -> {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            mImageView.setMinimumHeight(displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            mImageView.setMinimumWidth(displayMetrics.widthPixels);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("TAG", "Cannot load image" + e.getMessage()));
    }
```

I checked the storage path and everything is okay, what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you construct the path to the image:

```
mStorage.getReference().child("/animal_images/animals" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

It seems extremely unlikely that an image exist with the current timestamp of when the client requests it (`System.currentTimeMillis()`).

While using the timestamp in the client that **writes** the image is a good way to increase the chances that their filename will be unique, you can't use that same approach to then look up the image. You will need to have some way to communicate the timestamp of the image *from* the client that writes it *to* the client that reads it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the reference of the storage:

```java
mStorageReference = mStorage.getReference().child("/animal_images/animals" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

You wrote `System.currentTimeMillis()` whose value is not constant and will change from time to time. This means that you are basically searching for a name with a changed value because of the change in time. The image with the name with the new time does not exist. That is the reason you can't find it.